# How do I return the value inside of an Observable as the function in Angular 2+

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic3, observable, angularfire2

Ok so basically I have been struggling to get user details stored in firebase using the user ID.

I have a list of items that contain the user ID's in the object. I want this user id to be passed on to a function something like

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
    <p>{{getUsername(item.userId)}}</p>
</div>
```

in the html part of the app.

Then using this ID I want to pull username etc. which is stored in firebase as well and has the key as the same user id.

Following options are the things I tried already;

**Option 1 (Just a function at the same component)**

Outputs *undefined* which is I believe is because the function runs and 
returns the username variable before the subscription passes the data into 
it.

```
constructor(public db: AngularFireDatabase){}

getUserName(id) {
    var username;
    this.db.object('users/' + id).valueChanges().subscribe(v => {
        username = v['username'];
    });
    return username;
}
```

**Option 2 (created a service - Injectable so it passes it to object property)**

Outputs what I need but it shows the same for all the list elements

```
username;

constructor(public db: AngularFireDatabase){}

getUserName(id) {
    this.db.object('users/' + id).valueChanges().subscribe(v => {
        this.username = v['username'];
    });
    return this.username;
}
```

So what I need is something like option 1 but it needs to return the value inside the observable once the observable got the data and passed it to the variable inside the function so it doesn't return an *undefined* value.

Comment: Have you tried {{getUserName(item.userId) | async}}

Comment: I did that but it passes the whole object with all properties, I want it to display only ['username'] property of that object.

Comment: Then won't {{getUserName(item.userId).username | async}} work?

Comment: try `username = v.username`

Comment: {{getUserName(item.userId).username | async}} didn't work :/
neither username = v.username (I think it's because it's an object instead of array)

Comment: If you do console.log(v['username']), logs the name ?

Comment: @JorgeMejia yes it logs the name million times :D

Comment: In this case you can´t return the value for your subscribe, you have to do all inside the subscribe, if you have the main data you have to make a loop in your .ts calling your getUserName function and then create the final array with all the information, once you have your final array you can loop with *ngFor.

Comment: I thought of doing that but that but it's already getting the id from an ngFor element with item.id so I'm not sure how healthy would it be

Answer (score 3):

An important concept here is that the `Observable` is asynchronous, so you can't just "return" it's value as you might with a regular value. You have to wait for it to `emit` a value before you can return that value. Read more about that here: https://gist.github.com/staltz/868e7e9bc2a7b8c1f754.

For what you're trying to do specifically, I'd recommend just getting the `Observable` and using the 'async' pipe when you need it in the template.

```
getUserData(id): Observable<YourData> {
  return this.db.object('users/' + id).valueChanges();
}
```

Then in your template, you can do something like this:

```
<li *ngFor=let user of users"> {{ getUserData(user.id) | async }}</li>
```

---

If you know the user `id` off the bat in your component and you want to get the user data for that user and use it in your component code, you can do something like this:

```
userData: YourData;
@Input() id: any; // provided by parent component

ngOnInit() { // OnInit lifecycle hook
  this.db.object('users/' + this.id).valueChanges().subscribe(data => this.userData = data);
}
```

But remember to handle the cleanup of the subscription.

Comment: Thank you @vincecampanale for your answer however this passes the whole thing to the html which results with showing nothing at all. I need to pass the username only to the html.

Comment: for this answer try `{{(getUserData(user.id) | async)?.username}}`

Comment: `{{(getUserData(user.id) | async)?.username}}` didn't work either :/

Answer (score 0):

Try to do something like this:

You can´t return the value for your subscribe, you have to do all inside the subscribe, if you have the main data you have to make a loop in your .ts calling your getUserName function and then create the final array with all the information, once you have your final array you can loop with *ngFor in your HTML.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, ModalController } from 'ionic-angular';


@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-restaurant-menu',
  templateUrl: 'restaurant-menu.html',
})


export class YourClass {
     public userName : String;
     public navData  : any;
     public final_array : any  

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public) {
      this.navData = this.navParams.get('users');
      for(let user of this.navData){
          this.getUserName(user.id, user)
      }

  }


getUserName(id, user) {
    this.db.object('users/' + id).valueChanges().subscribe(v => {
        //here you have to create your final array whit the information
        this.final_array.push({user_data:user, user_name:v['username']})

    });
}


}
```

Then in your HTML you can use *ngFor

```
<p>{{ final_array.user_name }}<p>
```

This is an idea how can you resolve this problem

Comment: This isn't really what I need to be honest. Maybe I couldn't explain myself well.

The idea is that I have multiple users for the app and each one of them posts something to a shared feed. The username can be changed later on so I don't wanna post the username in the feed, instead I post the user id with the post item which then uses ngFor to list it on the page which works like a charm but then inside the ngFor loop I need to somehow take that user id and with a function I need to return the username of that user id which is in firebase as well.